# chromedriver, how to use predefind settings

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using **Chrome** as my Selenium test environment. Currently it is `chrome 67` and `chromedriver 2.40`

Sometimes during the test the browser is closed. When it happens I reopen the browser using the **chromedriver**.

The problem is that I loose the tab the test was testing. Is there a way to use "`On startup`" setting with the checkbox "`Continue where you left off`"?

Comment: Not what I need, the link you gave me deals with reconnection to a running chrome. No restarting one.

Comment: your binding language?

Comment: @cruisePandey the language I use for programming is Java.

Comment: you have mentioned that you are reopening  the browser using the chromedriver ? How did you do that ?

Comment: I create a new org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver (new Chromedriver(options)), and then i use it to open the tested server url.

Comment: Btw thank you for editing the question, it looks much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Each time **chromedriver** opens a browser, it creates **new profile**. The profile overwrites all the chrome settings. "`Continue where you left off`" option is part of the profile.

The solution is:

```
private static WebDriver startChrome() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=c:\\temp\\chromeProf"); // Set non-default profile
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    prefs.put("session.restore_on_startup", 1); // Edit profile preferences to be "Continue where you left off"
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); // Set preferences to ChromeOptions
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // Start driver with those options
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}
```